# jQuery UI onClose Call Function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
$('#myElement').datepicker(
    {
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        onClose: function() { 
            $(this).DoStuff;
            console.log('close');
        },
        beforeShowDay: nationalDays,
        minDate: new Date()
    }
);

function DoStuff() {
    console.log('DoStuff');
}
```

I am trying to call DoStuff when the datepicker closes.  My console shows "close", but not "DoStuff".  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$(this).DoStuff` will not call the `DoStuff` function on the `$(this)` object, but tries to access the `DoStuff` property of the `$(this)` object. In your case it will do nothing: it will be resolved as undefined, and as accessing a property will most likely have no side effect, nothing will happen.

Since your question is pretty basic I'm pretty sure there is a misunderstanding but here is how you call the `DoStuff` function:

```
DoStuff();
```

So this will suffice:

```
$('#myElement').datepicker(
    {
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        onClose: function() { 
            DoStuff();
            console.log('close');
        },
        beforeShowDay: nationalDays,
        minDate: new Date()
    }
);
```

---

**EDIT**:

Actually if you want to call a function on the jQuery object (although I'm not sure you really want to do that), you can extend the object like this:

```
jQuery.fn.DoStuff = function() {
    console.log('DoStuff');
}
```

And then you will be able to call `$(this).DoStuff()`. This way `this` will be the jQuery object inside your function, check this:

```
jQuery.fn.DoStuff = function() {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this[0]); //the first (and in this case the only) element selected by the selector
}

$('#myElement').DoStuff();
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you are not calling it

```
$(this).DoStuff; <-- missing the ()
```

And `DoStuff` is not attached to `$(this)` so it will not work either, I would expect to see extend, which your code does not have.

So it probably should be

```
DoStuff();
```

or

```
DoStuff.call($(this));
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).DoStuff()` implies `DoStuff()` is a member function of the object, which doesn't seem to be the case.

You should do `doStuff($(this));` instead and modify `doStuff()` to take in an argument.

```
function doStuff(el) {
  console.log('DoStuff called. Received element:');
  console.log(e);
}
```